Asymptotics for $f(z) = (z-1) \prod_n \frac{2}{z^{1/a_n}+1}$ with $1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + 1/a_3 + ... = 1.$
Let $Re(z) > 1$
Consider functions such as
$$f(z) = (z-1) ([2 / (z^{1/a_1} + 1)] [2 / (z^{1/a_2} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_3} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_4} + 1)][2 / (z^{1/a_5} + 1)]...)$$
or more formally
$$f(z) = (z-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{2}{z^{1/a_n}+1}$$
Where
$$1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + 1/a_3 + ... = 1.$$
and $a_n$ is a rising integer sequence.
Now clearly this function does not grow like any power of $x$.
For instance if $a_n = 2^n$ we get $f(z) = \ln(z)$.(*)
So what are the good asymptotics of $f(z)$ ?
Let $\pi(n)$ be the counting function of integers $a_n$ between $0$ and $n$.
Then it seems a good estimate for $f(z)$ when $z$ is close to the positive real line is
$$f(z) =  \exp(C \pi(\ln(z)))$$
For some value $C$.
Is this correct ? And how good is it exactly ?
For instance if $a_n = n(n+1)$ do we get
$$f(z) = O(\exp(\sqrt\ln(z))) $$
?
And if $a_n$ is sylvester's sequence do we get
$$f(z) =  O(\exp(C \pi(\ln(z))))$$
where $\pi$ counts the sylvester numbers ?

For instance let $z = \exp(400)$
and let $a_n = n(n+1)$.
Then $f(z) = \exp(q)$
where $20 < q < 21$.
thereby supporting the estimate
$$f(z) = O(\exp(\sqrt\ln(z))) $$





See the proof for the $\ln(x)$ case here
Why do we have $ \ln(z) = \frac{z-1}{e -1} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {z^{2^{-n}} + 1} $
(it is equivalent since the "$e$ parts" cancel to 2's)
and also somewhat related :
$(3x- 3)\prod_{n = 1}^∞\frac{\exp(2^{-n})+1}{x^{2^{-n}}+1}=(x^3-1)\prod_{n = 1}^∞\frac{\exp(2^{-n})+1}{x^{3 \cdot 2^{-n}}+1}$
I must also thank my mentor for this idea.
I will add a proof for the first link that I received from my mentor.
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/special-products


Some ideas I originally tried to avoid because it seems way to complicated, but since no easy answer occured, I share it ;
$$f(z) = (z-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{2}{z^{1/a_n}+1}$$
$$g(z) = \ln(\frac{f(z+1)}{z}) =  \ln(\prod_{n>0} \frac{2}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+1})$$
might be helpfull.
More precisely;
$$g(z) = \sum_{n>0} \ln(\frac{2}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+1})$$
$$\ln(z) = \frac{2(z-1)}{z+1} \sum_{n>0} \frac{1}{2n+1}(\frac{z-1}{z+1})^{2n}(*)$$
(* for $Im(z) = 0, Re(z) > 1)$
$$(\frac{\frac{2}{q+1}-1}{\frac{2}{q+1}+1})^2 = (\frac{q-1}{q+3})^2$$
so we get
$$\ln(\frac{2}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+1}) = 2 \frac{(z+1)^{1/a_n}-1}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+3} \sum_{m>0} \frac{1}{2m+1}(\frac{(z+1)^{1/a_n}-1}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+3})^{2m}$$
what converges at least exponentially fast at its tail for all $x>1$ since $(\frac{q-1}{q+3})^2$ goes to zero at least exponentially fast. Afterall $(\frac{q-1}{q+3})^2 < \frac{1}{9}$ when $x^v$ is sufficiently close to $1$.
Thus that series expansion works well.
So we arrive at
$$g(z) = \sum_{n>0}\ln(\frac{2}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+1}) $$
$$g(z) = \sum_{n>0} 2 \frac{(z+1)^{1/a_n}-1}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+3} \sum_{m>0} \frac{1}{2m+1}(\frac{(z+1)^{1/a_n}-1}{(z+1)^{1/a_n}+3})^{2m}$$
Next step is probably the generalized binomial theorem
$$(x+1)^t = 1 + \sum t_n x^n $$
where $t_n$ are expressible by gamma functions.
see :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series
and plugging that in the formula above.
At that point we get a messy expression that could work to get good asymptotics and in some cases maybe closed forms.
But I guess this is the hard way.
Which is why I did not mention it before.
Probably there are better tools.

Some additional ideas
$$\ln(\frac{1}{z} \prod_{n>0} (z^{1/a_n}+1)) = \sum_{n>0} \ln(\frac{z^{1/a_n}+1}{z^{1/a_n}}) =  \sum_{n>0} \sum_{k>0} \frac{1}{k(z^{1/a_n}+1)^k} $$
However the first term ($k=1$) does not converge if we sum over $n$ first.
Other series expansion for $\ln(z+1)$ and related functions seem to have the same issue of starting with something like $(a+bz)/(c+dz)$ and therefore having convergeance issues.
In fact the convergeance issues are even bigger since the higher terms do not converge either actually, since the convergeance of $s^..$ is to $1$ we get infinite additions of similar terms ...
Integral representations might be a way out. Or the idea above with $g(z)$. In fact the problem with convergeance here is the reason for the post of $g(z)$. But then it gets messy.

Not sure if this helps but
$$\int_0^\infty \prod_n^V \left(1+ s^{1/a_n}\right)^{-t} \mathrm{d} t = \frac{1}{\sum_n^V \ln(1 + s^{1/a_n})}$$
Notice however that when $V$ goes to infinity we get issues again, being the RHS equal to "$1 / \infty " $ no matter what $s$ is.
This seems to be solvable though :
$$\int_0^\infty \prod_n^V \left(1+ s^{1/a_n}\right)^{\frac{-t}{V \ln(2)}} \mathrm{d} t = \frac{V \ln(2)}{\sum_n^V \ln(1 + s^{1/a_n})}$$
and this looks familiar to me ??

Related :
Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\ln(e^{2/(n(n+1))} + 1) - \ln(2))$?


Maybe this is easier to handle to study the asymptotics: $$\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{z-1} + \sum_{n>0} \frac{1}{a_n(z^{1/a_n}+1)}$$

@Raskolnikov yeah I guess you are right in a way. taking the derivative removes the log.
However this series when turned into a taylor has a limited radius of convergeance. Im not sure what to do with that. But thanks for the comment.

I considered Mittag-Leffler expansion ...

@Raskolnikov It seems very similar but the product replaced by a sum ...

It also made me think of the Mittag-Leffler expansion. Except we have fractional powers of the $z$. I went this route because I thought of the product formula of $sin$ which can be connected to the Mittag-Leffler expansion of $cot$. But now, I don't know how to handle the asymptotics. I was hoping to do something with the residue theorem, but that might not be the appropriate tool.

Mittag-Leffler functions also came to my mind. One can approximate $\exp(z)(1 + z^q)$ with an entire function afterall ...

Taylor is never going to work, when you look at the asymptotics of the function, which you can do by looking around $0$ but with the substitution $z \to 1/z$, you'll see that it shoots of vertically. Think about the case where it's $-1/\ln(z)$. The inverse is $\exp(-1/z)$ which if you expand it around $0$ also does not have a Taylor expansion.

@Raskolnikov but the Mittag-Leffler functions are entire functions, so their radius is infinite and they approximate $\exp(z)(1 + z^q)$. Then again maybe the approximations are not good enough. Indeed Taylor is difficult. But so is Lambert or Fourier and Laplace transforms seem hard too. Im a bit lost.

I wanted to put down some interesting intermediary results, which while not an answer to your question might help you further.
First, the trick of your teacher can be generalized for any base $b$ other than base $2$, i.e.
$$\ln(z) = (z-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{b}{\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}z^{k/b^n}} \; .$$
In particular for base $3$
$$\ln(z) = (z-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{3}{1+z^{1/3^n}+z^{2/3^n}} \; .$$
Other point, take the sequence $a_n=3^n/2$, which is increasing and sums to $1$. If we consider the function
$$C(z) = (z-1) \prod_{n>0} \frac{2}{1+z^{2/3^n}} \; .$$
Could we apply your teacher's trick here? I think we can. Note that the product
$$\prod_{n>0} \frac{1+z^{2/3^n}}{2}$$
also corresponds to a kind of Riemann sum but with a ternary expansion where digit $1$ never appears. Now, this does not lead to an integration over the Lebesgue measure of the set, since the set is the Cantor ternary set which has Lebesgue measure $0$, but over the Haar measure of this set. (At least that is what I surmise, I have not strictly proven it.) Hence,
$$\prod_{n>0} \frac{1+z^{2/3^n}}{2} = \int_0^1 z^t H_C(dt)$$
where $H_C$ is representing that Haar measure over the Cantor ternary set.
Third point, as I suggested you can look at the asymptotic behaviour by substituting $z\to z^{-1}$ and thus studying the behaviour around $0$. Also switching to the logarithm of the function and taking the derivative transforms the problem to studying the asymptotics of
$$g(z)=\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{z-1} + \sum_{n>0} \frac{1/a_n}{z^{1/a_n}+1}$$
and note that
$$g(1/z) = -g(z) \, .$$
This means that actually the behaviour around $0$ and around $\infty$ are tied.

Your first and " other " (not second ?) point were already known to me, even way before I asked for a proof of the $\ln(x)$ identity many years ago.  But thank you for writing it down. As for you last point, I have some doubts about it at first sight. But I need to analyse it. Im not sure if you did not confuse with lambert series and/or forgot a term. Thanks for the effort anyway and I will think about it +1
